# Hide a Column name in a list View sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm using a list as a list of hyperlinks so there's no need to sort ascending etc but the "Name" is annoying, how can I hide the name of the column but still show that column's data.

Comment: is this in a default list view (i.e. the standard AllItems.aspx of a list) or in a custom page where you show the items using a dataformwebpart or an SPGridVIew?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to blank when `OnRowBinding` is fired

Comment: How are you binding to the list?